# Whats the difference between incrementing a pointer compared to incrementing the elements of the array the pointer points to?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, increment

I'm trying to understand what the difference between these two functions is:

```
void funk1(char* goal, char* source){
int i = 0;
while((goal[i]= source[i]) != ’\0’)
i++; }
```

and

```
void funk2(char* goal, char* source){
while((*goal= *source) != ’\0’){
  goal++;
source++;
} }
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: they do the same thing, I think. Why do you think there is a difference?

Comment: A) This looks like a kind of weak re-implementation of `strcpy()` which isn't safe. At the very least use `strncpy()`. B) In C++ please, for your own sake, use `std::string` so you can avoid the unending misery that is C strings. C) If you are doing stuff like this maybe a `for` loop is better.

Answer (score 2):

> Whats the difference between incrementing a pointer compared to incrementing the elements of the array the pointer points to?

Incrementing a pointer (or more generally, any iterator) modifies the pointer. The resulting pointer will point to the next element of the array.

Indirecting through a pointer and incrementing the pointed object modifies the pointed object. How increment modifies the object depends on the type of the object.

---

Note that in neither of your examples do you increment element of an array. In the first you increment the variable `i` which is an integer that you use as an index, while in the second you increment two pointers.

Answer (score 0):

`goal[i]` is equivalent to `*(goal + i)`, so both implementations work.

Note: none of these functions are actually "incrementing the elements of the array the pointer points to". The elements of the array are modified with `operator=`, but the `++` just modifies the pointers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will probably create the same executable for both cases. But if you will compile with explicit flag that tells the compiler "Do not optimize", funk2 is a bit faster (note that on todays modern computer it is neglect).
Why?

1. funk1 requires 4 register while funk2 requires only 3.
2. Because the operation `goal[i]` is equivalent to `*(goal + i)`, which is a heavier computation than `++`.